# How can i read a directory from another machine which is using windows OS using java

Tags: java

I am trying to read the directory from another machine (files located under **tomacat/webapps/ROOT/directory**) and to display available files under that directory using URL class. can anybody suggest some ideas.

Thanks in Advance,
JAI

Answer (score 0):

You can make a path with Paths.get("tomacat","webapps","ROOT","directory"), this should make the correct path on each OS. Then you can find all the files under that directory with: `Directorystream ds = Files.newDirectorystream(Paths.get(...))`. You can iterate through the result with `for(Path file:ds){}`

Comment: I am trying to fetch directory from "http://<ipaddr>:<portnumber>/directory_name/"  from another remote server. By the way it is working for local machine but not working for remote machine to access the directory.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not sure but have you tried this: `URL url = new URL(urlStr);`. Then open the connection:
`java.net.URLConnection con = url.openConnection();`, make an inputstreamReader with: `InputStreamReader in = con.getInputStream()` `String file = in.readline(); while(file != null){...}` should give you the names of the files under the directory

Comment: Instead of accessing tomcat directory, i have tried to access a shared folder which resolved my purpose and it is working.

Comment: As i mentioned in previos comment it was working fine and now am facing the belowexception. jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC000009A
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:510)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:610)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:269)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:225)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:147)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:791)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:761)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send
Any suggestions please?